# grunt.js - concat javascripts into function call

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'd like to concat many Javascript files into function call.

As a result I want to get something like this:

```
(function() {

  // contents of file 1
  // contents of file 2
  // contents of file ..

})()
```

In grunt-contrib-concat package there's no such option. Also I didn't find any package for this.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this issue with grunt-contrib-concat. Use the banner and footer option like this:

```
 concat: {
    options: {
        banner: '(function() {\n',
        footer: '\n})()'
    },
    dist: {
       src: ['file1.js', 'file2.js'],
       dest: ''
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I found later. :) Thanks!